# VerticalStackLayout with expanded children

Tags: xaml, maui, .net-7.0

According to [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/layouts/verticalstacklayout?view=net-maui-7.0) `VerticalStackLayout` is more performant alternative to `StackLayout`. Apparently this is because [the `Orientation` property does not need to be calculated](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/6766).

But I can't make `VerticalStackLayout` work with expanded children the same way as with `StackLayout`. I can't find any information on why `VerticalStackLayout` does not work with expanded children, see the example below.

**How can I make `VerticalStackLayout` behave the same way as `StackLayout` with children that have `AndExpand` vertical option?**

### Code example

StackLayout -- the correct behavior, BoxViews are expanded

```xml
<StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" BackgroundColor="Yellow">
    <BoxView BackgroundColor="White" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" />
    <BoxView BackgroundColor="Red" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" />
</StackLayout>
```

[image: StackLayout with expanded children]

VerticalStackLayout -- BoxViews are not expanded at all

```xml
<VerticalStackLayout BackgroundColor="Yellow">
    <BoxView BackgroundColor="White" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" />
    <BoxView BackgroundColor="Red" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" />
</VerticalStackLayout>
```

Result:

[image: VerticalStackLayout with expanded children]

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue on maui you can follow up it on [github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/1601).

Comment: The issue is closed and the PRs merged since August 2021

Comment: Yes, but the problem happens on my side too. The Boxview appears if you give it the height.